# WebRTC iOS: Filtering camera stream from RTCCameraVideoCapturer. Conversion from RTCFrame to CVPixelBuffer

Tags: ios, webrtc, video-capture, cvpixelbuffer

I found the git below is simple and efficient by using `func capturer(_ capturer: RTCVideoCapturer, didCapture frame: RTCVideoFrame)` of `RTCVideoCapturerDelegate`. You get `RTCVideoFrame` and then convert to `CVPixelBuffer` to modify.

https://gist.github.com/lyokato/d041f16b94c84753b5e877211874c6fc

However, I found Chronium says nativeHandle to get PixelBuffer is no more available(link below). I tried frame.buffer.pixelbuffer..., but, looking at framework > Headers > RTCVideoFrameBuffer.h, I found CVPixelBuffer is also gone from here!

https://codereview.webrtc.org/2990253002

Is there any good way to convert `RTCVideoFrame` to `CVPixelBuffer`?
Or do we have better way to modify captured video from RTCCameraVideoCapturer?

Below link suggests modifying sdk directly but hopefully we can achieve this on Xcode.

[How to modify (add filters to) the camera stream that WebRTC is sending to other peers/server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41038336/how-to-modify-add-filters-to-the-camera-stream-that-webrtc-is-sending-to-other)

Answer (score 6):

can you specify what is your expectation? because you can get pixel buffer from RTCVideoframe easily but I feel there can be a better solution if you want to filter video buffer than sent to Webrtc, you should work with **RTCVideoSource**.

you can get buffer with
   [as seen](https://gist.github.com/lyokato/d041f16b94c84753b5e877211874c6fc)

```
    RTCCVPixelBuffer *buffer = (RTCCVPixelBuffer *)frame.buffer;
    CVPixelBufferRef imageBuffer = buffer.pixelBuffer;
```

**(with latest SDK and with local video camera buffer only)**

but in the sample i can see that filter will not work for remote.
[image]

i have attached the screenshot this is how you can check the preview as well.

Comment: Hi Sumit, thanks for your comment. As I described in my question, nativeHandle function is removed 1.5 years ago. Pls see the Chronium link. I built sdk by Chronium depot_tools, not pod, to adopt bitcode.

Comment: I have edited my answer please check it, I believe it will gives you the image buffer you are looking for.

Comment: Hi Sumit. [RTCVideoframe](https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/master/sdk/objc/base/RTCVideoFrame.h), [RTCCVPixelBuffer](https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/master/sdk/objc/base/RTCVideoFrameBuffer.h), [RTCI420Buffer](https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/master/sdk/objc/base/RTCI420Buffer.h) These are links to most updated = master sdk. They show no property or function of Frame and Buffer gives access to CVPixelBuffer. I know it WAS available, but not anymore. So I ended up building a new capturer implementing RTCVideoCapturer. Thanks much for your time and comments, anyway!

Comment: Hi @GiraffWombat it will work you have to try it first I just check and I am able to get to cvpixelbuffer.

Comment: In my whole day on tacking this, your answer pops up several times. It took me a while to follow the code. At the end, very happy to see it working for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is there any way to capture audio from ongoing stream?

Comment: as I know there is no direct way to get the remote audio stream however you can get remote audio stream by customizing SDK source code by your own.

Comment: I wish there was a way to upvote this answer more than I already did. Sharing this kind of deep information from a really experienced developer (I mean after 7 years of Xcode I only now see that (i) screen for the first time!) is absolutely saving me hours and hours and thousands of dollars.